# How to use special charactors in regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I want to use some special charactors such as " and . I am new to java. I have tried some regular expressions and i want to use " and \ in the expression. Since my regular expression takes between ",i cannot use " symble for the regular expression. Here is my word that should extract `["FacebarNavigation","setPageQuery",[],[{"structure":[{"text":" (some text)` In here after text":" there is some text as well.so please try to help me to extract this from the txt file . Thank you.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class RegularExpression_fyp {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    String pattern = "";

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

     //["FacebarNavigation","setPageQuery",[],[{"structure":[{"text":" 
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("F:\\testing3.txt");
    FileChannel channel = input.getChannel();

    ByteBuffer bbuf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, (int) channel.size());
    CharBuffer cbuf = Charset.forName("8859_1").newDecoder().decode(bbuf);

    Matcher matcher = r.matcher(cbuf);

  if (matcher.find( )) {
     System.out.println("Found value: " + matcher.group(0) );

  } else {
     System.out.println("NO MATCH");
  }
  }
```

Comment: But your pattern is empty string.

Comment: you have to escape them for the regex and escape them for java, so to match a `"` you do `\\\"`

Comment: It seems you're working with JSON; why don't you use an actual JSON parser instead of a regex?

Comment: Trying to parse JSON with regex is a very bad idea. You should use serialization frameworks such as GSON or Jackson.

Comment: Please gives us the input and what you want to extract exactly, your sample input looks unterminated., if what you wish is what is after the "text": `.*\"text\":\"(.*?)\".*` should be enougt (I'm just escaping the `"` here for java, they're not a regex special char.

Comment: in a large text file i want to search 
,["FacebarNavigation","setPageQuery",[],[{"structure":[{"text":"sam de mel","type"

and this sam de mel is a name and it can have many charactores and it is different from one txt to another. so i want to search this pattern and get the name out of it. Thank you for your grate answer.

Comment: thankz tensibai for yout answer i have change it littlebit and here is my new regular expression \\[\\{\\\"text\\\"\\:\\\"\\w[A-Za-z0-9]